# Should private citizens be legally allowed to sell their citizenship to a prospective buyer?

Tags: democracy, citizenship, capitalism

Some states give dividend to citizenships; there are movements for that.
Some, [like Vanuatu](http://www.goldenvisas.com/vanuatu/), allow people to buy citizenship; there are movements for that too.

For background, there are a number of reputable explanations and discussions of states that sell citizenship to prospective buyers: ([2](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/japp.12292), [3](http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20170530-why-citizenship-is-now-a-commodity), [4](https://www.google.com/search?q=citizenship%20market%20value&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b), [5](https://www.peter-boettke.com/app/download/7120487765/Freiman+-+Should+States+Allow+Markets+in+Citizenship.pdf)).

**Question:**

If states are allowed to sell citizenship, should states allow their citizens to sell their citizenship as well?

What are  problems that can arise if private citizens can legally sell their citizenship, and can these be adequately addressed?

Comment: I've thought about it. But some other questions also advocate something and they're allowed

Comment: I modified the questions to something simpler.

Comment: This may look like advocating something. I don't know what to say. However, other questions also seem to advocate something too and yet answerable. Can anyone tell me what's the limit?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I think this (and others as well) post is too long for a start. A question should try to be mainly just that: a political question. Of course, some context and references are required to make it answerable (not too broad), but this OP contains quite a debate. This post could end at "And, citizenship have market value." (maybe add some references to articles that show examples of citizenship being bought).

Comment: I changed the question to take into account that similar ideas are plenty

Comment: I removed the unnecessary parts of the question as suggested by Alexei. Questions should not try to answer themselves in the question. Also, you were only listing advantages, so you gave the impression that you are promoting a political cause.

Comment: Let's say I want to bomb country X. If I buy a citizenship of country X, from some random person, country X can't turn me away at it's borders, whereas previously they could have. Country X, if it sold citizenships, would be able to *decline to sell me one*

Comment: What would be the point?

Comment: @Caleth, If they know you want to bomb them, then perhaps they can't turn you away at its borders, but they can put you in jail on entry.

Comment: @ugoren there is that nuissance of *due process*. You can turn away suspicious foreigners without any issues, in many countries you cannot jail a citizen (or even a foreigner), no matter how suspicious, without some evidence and without judicial review.

Comment: The edit towards "Should private citizens be allowed..." instead of the previous "What are the benefits and problems" makes the question basically opinion-based. As a rule of thumb, "Should" questions should be avoided as there is no right answer.

Comment: The real problem with this plan is that citizenship is not the citizen's to give.  Citizens of some countries can renounce their citizenship of that country, but they cannot give it to someone else.  The only entity with the power to grant citizenship is the country itself.

Answer (score 8):

Why would a state allow this?

Suppose a state decided, like Vanuatu, that selling citizenship for money is a good idea. Now what if a new citizen buys his citizenship from an existing one, rather than a the state? What's the difference?

- It's harder (though still possible) for the state to supervise this and prevent unwanted sales.
- The money goes to the selling citizen, rather than the state.
- The selling citizen loses his citizenship, and likely leaves the country (taking his newly earned money with him).

From the state's point of view, these are all disadvantages.

Answer (score 4):

Governments sell citizenship to:

- Raise capital
- Boost their population
- Raise their profile

The problem with a citizen selling citizenship is that they may become stateless. This would lead to various problems. They may no longer be eligible for benefits, to be employed, to travel abroad etc.

If the option was there, then some people would make a poor decision to surrender citizenship for short-term cash.

Comment: The UN have gone as far as saying (in article 15 of the universal declaration of human rights) that everyone has the right to a nationality. This means that somebody who's provably stateless gets priority in many jurisdictions when applying for citizenship.

Comment: The problem of statelessness exists anyway because citizens can renounce their citizenship.  Some countries allow this only when the citizen in question has other citizenships or plans to acquire them, but others have no such restriction.

Comment: Then make that restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are starting with questionable assumptions about the relationship between the citizen and the state.

- Citizens do not **own** their citizenship, to dispose as they see fit. It is sometimes, but not always, inheritable, but in those cases a child does not have to wait for the death of the parent to gain citizenship. So why *should* citizens be able to sell it?
- Citizens may be able to "pass" citizenship to spouses or adopted children, either immediately or by fast-tracking the application. Generally it is illegal to do so for money.
- When states sell citizenship, they generally pretend that they're merely fast-tracking the appication of would-be immigrants who want to "invest in the local economy." One could argue that this is no different from the practice of fast-tracking applicants with firm job offers, or with skills deemed useful.

Regarding problems on the hypothetical sale:

- Would the seller abandon his or her original citizenship? Would this be legal only if the seller does not become stateless, or even then? (Note that there are states which do not want to let the children of citizens go, even if they never set foot in that state. What if the second citizenship is such a case?)
- What happens to obligations owned by the selling citizen to the state, e.g. draft to military service, jury duty, taxes owed? Would the sale require that the buyer takes them over?
- If a citizen goes into bankruptcy proceedings, can the creditors seize the citizenship and sell it off to cover debts? Would that require the ex-citizen to emigrate? Where?

Comment: citizens don't own citizenship. Actually do they even own the country? Would extending property right of a country to citizens help?

Comment: @J.Chang, many constitutions declare that sovereignty rests with the people as a group. That is not *ownership* in the sense one might own shares in a corporation, and trying to cast it in those terms will lead to states that were not envisioned by the writers of the constitutions.